# How to run aiohttp app from pytest fixture

Tags: python-3.x, socket.io, pytest, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have system under test(SUT) that requires socketio-server. This server would response to SUT in some functionality. So socketio-server is necessary enviroment for my SUT.

For socketio-server i chose aiohttp with python-socketio.

Example of functionality my socketio-server:

```
from aiohttp import web
import socketio


sio = socketio.AsyncServer()
app = web.Application()
sio.attach(app)


@sio.on('commands')
async def message_handler(sid, msg):
    if msg['data']['command'] == 'terminal_settings_info':
        response_msg = {'handler': msg['handler'],
                        'data': {'result': 1,
                                 'is_success': True,
                                 'TerminalID': 5,
                                 'request_id': msg['data']['request_id']}}
        await sio.emit('commands', response_msg)

    elif msg['data']['command'] == 'get_agent_info':
        response_msg = {'handler': msg['handler'],
                        'data': {'result': 1,
                                 'is_success': True,
                                 'terminal_address': 'Zelenograd',
                                 'agent_support_phone': '8-888-88-88-88',
                                 'mf_retail': True,
                                 'request_id': msg['data']['request_id']}}
        await sio.emit('commands', response_msg)

    else:
        raise ValueError('Unknown request.\nMessage: ' + msg.__repr__())


web.run_app(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=1234)
```

---

**I want to SetUp this socketio-server from pytest fixture before run tests and TearDown after tests complete. So, this server must non-blocks pytest thread.
This is my purpose.
How can i do this?**

I'm pretty good in pytest and syncrhonous code execution in Python, but newbi for async programming(asyncio, aiohttp) and newbi for using threading, subprocess or multiprocessing.

Comment: FWIW, you may want to check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62012361/how-to-write-pytest-fixture-for-asyncio-stream-server/63937972#63937972 You should probably just use the aiohttp plugin from the answer below, but I go into some detail over there about running async servers cooperatively with unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://github.com/aio-libs/pytest-aiohttp -- aiohttp plugin for pytest